# How come my bash scripts in my Linux server doesn't recognize asterisk as all files with the same prefix?

Tags: linux

I've a Linux instance with a cron job running a script that sends my ssl logs to a s3 bucket in my aws account.
The script that is failing looks like this:

```
/var/log/httpd/*log {
    
      compress
      compresscmd /bin/gzip
      compressoptions -9
      compressext .gz
    
      dateext
      dateformat _%Y-%m-%d.log.%s
    
      rotate 14
      nomail
      missingok
      #size 5k
      create 640 root root
    
      sharedscripts
      postrotate
      sudo /sbin/service httpd reload > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    
      BUCKET=*********
    
      SITE=*******
    
      sudo /usr/bin/s3cmd sync /var/log/httpd/access_log_*.gz s3://${BUCKET}/${SITE}/access_logs/access_logs/
      sudo /usr/bin/s3cmd sync /var/log/httpd/ssl_access_log_*.gz s3://${BUCKET}/${SITE}/access_logs/ssl_access_logs/
      sudo /usr/bin/s3cmd sync /var/log/httpd/error_log_*.gz s3://${BUCKET}/${SITE}/error_logs/error_logs/
      sudo /usr/bin/s3cmd sync /var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log_*.gz s3://${BUCKET}/${SITE}/error_logs/ssl_error_logs/
      sudo /usr/bin/s3cmd sync /var/log/httpd/ssl_request_log_*.gz s3://${BUCKET}/${SITE}/request_logs/ssl_request_logs/
    
      endscript
    
    }
```

and the output is:

```
ERROR: Parameter problem: Invalid source: '/var/log/httpd/access_log_*.gz' is not an existing file or directory
ERROR: Parameter problem: Invalid source: '/var/log/httpd/ssl_access_log_*.gz' is not an existing file or directory
ERROR: Parameter problem: Invalid source: '/var/log/httpd/error_log_*.gz' is not an existing file or directory
ERROR: Parameter problem: Invalid source: '/var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log_*.gz' is not an existing file or directory
ERROR: Parameter problem: Invalid source: '/var/log/httpd/ssl_request_log_*.gz' is not an existing file or directory
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/httpd/*log '
```

It looks like my bash script for some reason doesn't recognize how to use the asterisk and I couldn't figure out why.

Thanks alot.

Edit:
I'm sure these file prefix exists in the folder, and I'm running the script as root.

Comment: Can you verify that files exists with the given patterns in the directory `/var/log/httpd`. And that the directory is searchable for the shell executing the commands.

Comment: If you are running the script as root, then why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: That's not a bash script. Retag the question properly please.

Answer (score 2):

In scripts or on your terminal, the path glob expansion is handled by the shell (bash, zsh, etc) and not the program/or the command itself (*although it depends on the program/cmd implementation)

For your `logrotate` config, the postrotate commands are 'exec' by logrotate and not shell. To have a shell invocation so that the '*' can be expanded, try invoking the command using `/bin/bash -c`

Eg:

```
sudo bash -c "/usr/bin/s3cmd sync /var/log/httpd/access_log_*.gz s3://${BUCKET}/${SITE}/access_logs/access_logs/"
```